# How Can Upload fingure print (Bio Matric) data to mysql server realtime

Tags: mysql

I want To upload  fingerprint machine  generated data into mysql database real time or
specific time without  any user action (human action).
is there any way to do this.
i search on google  i found one touch data update on mysql database device.
but i want to know is there any api to transfer data to mysql database without (human action)
like corn tab..

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do this. when you registered user on the  fingerprint machine then registration id is generated that you can store on server for further processing....